# Google Assistant "Talk to ..." on Default intent using simulator

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I am struggling with Google Assistant configuration from the Google Actions console.

While I have already uploaded a pretty simple `action.json` file using `gactions` which only should response with a static fullfillment when I say "Hey Google, talk to Rasp Pi" (while "Rasp Pi" is the display name defined in the Invocation tab)

I opened up the Simulator and it already recommend me the sentence "Talk to Rasp Pi"

Once I clicked "Talk to Rasp Pi" an error occurred:
"We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again."

Below is the action.json I have successfully uploaded.

```
{
"manifest": {
    "displayName": "Example",
    "invocationName": "Example",
    "category": "PRODUCTIVITY"
},
"locale": "de",
"actions": [
    {
        "name": "MAIN",
        "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
        "fulfillment": {
            "staticFulfillment": {
                "templatedResponse": {
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "simpleResponse": {
                                "textToSpeech": "Was kann ich tun?"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN"
        }
    },
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After using the `gactions test --project <project-id> --action_package action.json` I have received the below message and I was to test it from another google enabled device. **But not yet on the simulator**

```
Pushing the app for the Assistant for testing...
Your app for the Assistant for project speech-cd6e3 is now ready for testing on Actions on Google enabled devices or the Actions Web Simulator at https://console.actions.google.com/project/<project-id>/simulator/
```

Comment: What documentation did you read to put together this action package? It seems like an unusable hybrid between Actions SDK and Google Assistant SDK.

Comment: Well, actually its nothing else than not using dialogflow and instead uploading the action.json to provide similar functionality - https://developers.google.com/actions/sdk/create-a-project

Comment: Although in that guide they define a webhook for responses instead of doing static responses.

Comment: That is true, but even with a webhook I had to still do a `gactions test` to make it available

Answer (score 0):

The answer is pretty simple.

As already mentioned in my own question, it seems to be important to do a `gactions test --project <project-id> --action_package action.json` to make it available for the simulator (and other devices)

Also important to note is, whenever you receive the below message:

**We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.***

this may be because of an incorrect definition in the actions.json OR when the fulfillment does not contain a response (E.g. simpleResponse -> textToSpeech)

So, I resolved this by doing

1. `gactions update [...]`
2. followed by `gactions test [...]`
3. always make sure action.json syntax is correct (spelling mistakes)
4. make sure that at least one "textToSpeech" is returned as fullfillment

Last but not least be a bit patient on the simulator to accept the new uploaded definition